# Performance impacts of running three simultaneous hub connections?

Tags: signalr

I am building a web application that current utilizes two SignalR hubs:

```
ChatHub - User communication
ControlHub - User manipulates controls and receives responses from server
```

I want to add a third hub: `GuideHub` that will be responsible for determining whether or not a user has completed a set of tasks that they are assigned on the website.  Technically, this hub will be active whenever ChatHub is active (they share a page element) but they serve thematically different purposes.  Generally, users will only be actively communicating across one hub at a time.

I know that premature optimization is usually no good, in this scenario, I need to plan ahead about how I am going to enable these features to scale well.  Is this architecture scale-able or should I combine `ControlHub` and `GuideHub` to reduce the number of open connections users will have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.x support multiple hubs over one connection

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs